Cannot resolve @types alias path in webpack
I have a webpack config where I add alias paths:
webpack.config.js
...
alias: {
 '@src': paths.src,
 '@types': resolve(paths.src, 'types'),
 '@assets': resolve(paths.src, 'assets'),   
 '@components': resolve(paths.src, 'presentation/components'),
},
...

tsconfig.json
...
"paths": {
  "@src/*": ["src/*"],
  "@types/*": ["src/types/*"],
  "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
  "@components/*": ["src/presentation/components/*"]
}
...

All works fine using them like this
import Sidebar from '@components/sidebar';

But for some reason @types does not work:
import type { Podcast } from '@types/podcasts';

I tried to restart vscode, remove type from the import and nothing, there's not a problem with the types themselves as this also works
import type { Podcast } from '@src/types/podcasts';

But I cannot understand why @types does not work
